# Case insensitive search query in jenssegers laravel/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, php-mongodb

How do I query case insensitive search or where condition.

For Example, I have collection tags

```
{
_id:"id1",
tag:"abc"
}
{
_id:"id2",
tag:"ABC"
}
```

If i query `::where('tag','abc')`

I am getting the only id1 document.
How do I query it as case-insensitive, so that I can retrieve both documents(id1 and id2)?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution by my self.

I need to use like operator without pattern matching (%) symbol.

```
ModelName::where('tag','like','abc');
```

This will return both documents ( id1,id2).

Please let me know if there is any better solution exists for this query.